# Android SQLite: "Cursor has no data" error

Tags: android, sqlite

After setDist3(..) code stops by saying cursor has no data. What might be the problem! all the table and column name are matched. Why at the middle of the code it returns the else statement?

```
    public List<Information> findTwoBus(Integer fromNode, Integer toNode){

            List<Information> l_info = new ArrayList<Information>();

            String SQL ="SELECT '2' AS type, s1.`bid` AS busid1, s3.`bid` AS busid2, '0' AS busid3, ch1.`changeid` AS changeid1, '0' AS changeid2,(s2.`distance` - s1.`distance`) AS dist1,(s4.`distance` - s3.`distance`) AS dist2, '0' AS dist3 FROM `changestations` AS ch1, `routes` AS b1, `routes` AS b2,`routestations` AS s1 INNER JOIN `routestations` AS s2 ON s1.`bid` = s2.`bid` INNER JOIN `routestations` AS s3 ON s2.`pid` = s3.`pid` INNER JOIN `routestations` AS s4 ON s3.`bid` = s4.`bid`WHERE s1.`pid` = :from AND s2.`pid` = ch1.`changeid` AND s4.`pid` = :to AND s2.`distance` > s1.`distance` AND s4.`distance` > s3.`distance` AND b1.`id` = s1.`bid` AND b2.`id` = s3.`bid` AND b1.`similarity` <> b2.`similarity` ORDER BY (dist1 + dist2)  LIMIT 5";
            Cursor res = myDataBase.rawQuery(SQL,new String[]{String.valueOf(fromNode), String.valueOf(toNode)});
            if(res.getCount() > 0){
                res.moveToFirst();
                do{
                    Information info = new Information();

                    info.setType(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("type"))));
                    info.setBusid1(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("busid1"))));
                    info.setBusid2(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("busid2"))));
                    info.setBusid3(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("busid3"))));
                    info.setChangeid1(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("changeid1"))));
                    info.setChangeid2(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("changeid2")))); 
                  //code runs upto here    
                   info.setDist3(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dist3"))));

                 // from here it says that cursor has no data in logcat and crashes
                    info.setDist2(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dist2"))));

                    info.setDist1(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dist1"))));

                    l_info.add(info);
                    res.moveToNext();
                } while(!res.moveToLast());
            } else{
                Log.e("SQL Query Error","Cursor has no data");}
            return l_info;
        }
```

05-17 17:33:16.860 8665-8665/com.example.tripathee.gantabya E/SQL Query Error: Cursor has no data

05-17 17:33:16.860 8665-8665/com.example.tripathee.gantabya W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4167ec80)

Comment: Please post the log cat

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem in the while statement:

```
   while(!res.moveToLast());
```

Shouldn't it be this?:

```
   while(!res.isAfterLast());
```

Comment: code crashes before getting to that statement! I am beginner in android! can you please provide me difference between them! Thank you

Comment: moveToLast() will try to move cursor to the last row, returning a boolean wether the move succeded or not.

isAfterLast() returns whether the cursor is pointing to the position after the last row or not.

When you iterate over a cursor you usually want to start on the first position with: moveToFirst(), iterate it with moveToNext() and check if it has reached the end with isAfterLast().

Comment: I would advise you to debug the cursor content with 

      DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(res);

and check if it matches your getColumnIndex parameters.

Comment: thank you for your further explanation! I will try to debug the cursor as you said!

Comment: Sorry but how to use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(res); can you please guide me

Comment: DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(res) will return the contents of the cursor in a string.
To throw it in your logcat:  System.out.print(DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(res));  or Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(res)); are two valid options.

Comment: Yeah it matchess!! It is showing all the datas... values of all dis1, dis2 , dis3 is showing! magical code! but it crashes! can u figure out?